# What is the vertical red bar during combat in the Division

Tags: the-division

Sometimes during combat in the dark zone an npc will get a vertical red bar around them (similar to loot but red)... What does it signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical red stripe is the first phase of a successful pulse.  After the vertical red line appears a red outline will then appear around the character.  You will notice that if you lose line-of-sight on the character the character model will be replaced with red blocks that roughly represent the character's location.

This affect can come about as a result of using the "pulse" skill or by successfully hitting an enemy with a head-shot with the "precision" talent enabled for your character.  When an affect is applied to a target after a successful attack this is usually referred to as a "proc."

Also, I am not sure if it is by design or a glitch, but I have noticed that this "headshot pulse" or "pulse proc" can sometimes be activated even if the player does not have the appropriate talent enabled.

Comment: Does this effect also appear when scoring a headshot with at least four pieces of the Sentry's Call gear set? Each headshot (up to three) adds an additional 15% damage that stacks to 45%.